# VB Create Next Folder in Numerical Sequence

Tags: vb.net

We have a structure of folders much like the following:

```
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15061089
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15061090
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15061091
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15071092
....
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1101 - 1200/15071111
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15071131
```

etc

There are 100 project folders in each directory and the numerical sequence is the last 4 digits of the 8 digit number. The first 2 digits are the year and the 3-4th are the month. So YYMM1234

I have written some code that creates the folder and fills it with what I need but currently you have to choose the folder it will sit in and then choose the number to name the folder as.

I need as follows and am still a relative beginner so go easy please:

Search "Y:/Sample Code Sequence/" subdirectories and find the folder where the last 4 digits are the highest number, we can therefore determine the next number in sequence.

Put that with the YY and MM preceding it to define the name of the new project and therefore directory name.

If the folder exists that should contain the new folder then that's where I need the folder created ie if the next number is xxxx1503 and the folder "1501 - 1600" already exists, I can create the folder in there....

But, if the next number in sequence is 1601, the folder "1601 - 1700" won't exist yet and I therefore need to create it and then create the folder within it.

I would love to change the directory system layout to make this easier but it is an established system that I am not allowed to change!

Thanks in advance,

Jamie

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` will create the entire path

Comment: What happens after you have 9,999 folders? (Also, still waiting to hear what your actual question is.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your question actually is. I'm just going to assume that you don't know how to go about doing what you need.

First, let's start with some basics. We need to know what parent directory we are searching - and we need to be able to capture the current project number for valid subfolders.

```
Dim parentFolder = "Y:\Sample Code Sequence"

Dim regex = New Regex( _
    "^.{" _
    & parentFolder.Length.ToString() _
    & "}\\\d{4} - \d{4}\\\d{4}(\d{4})$")
```

Now we want to query the folders to retrieve the maximum project number and add one to this.

```
Dim query = _
    From d1 In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentFolder) _
    From d2 In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(d1) _
    Let m = regex.Match(d2) _
    Where m.Success _
    Let count = Integer.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value) _
    Order By count Descending _
    Select count

Dim nextProject = query.FirstOrDefault() + 1
```

Finally we just build the new project folder name and create it.

```
Dim newProjectFolder = String.Format( _
    "{0}\{1:0000} - {2:0000}\{3:00}{4:00}{5:0000}", _
    parentFolder, _
    ((nextProject - 1) \ 100) * 100 + 1, _
    ((nextProject - 1) \ 100) * 100 + 100, _
    DateTime.Now.Year Mod 100, _
    DateTime.Now.Month, _
    nextProject)

Directory.CreateDirectory(newProjectFolder)
```

I've tested this code and it appears to work fine.